# How to forbid fullscreen for an X-Forwarded window

Tags: ssh, fullscreen, x11-forwarding

I am running an application via SSH and X-Forwarding. The application runs automatically in fullscreen mode which is very unhandy.

Is there any way to run the remote application in a windowed mode and to suppress its fullscreen mode?

Background Specs:
Ubuntu 18.04, X11, OpenBox

Comment: For any arbitrary program or do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: In my case it is a java application.